# When there are two power supply circuit, the voltage solution problem?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am an electronic beginner and I do not understand how Uab solves this circuit.

[image]

I know how this value get, but I do not understand why it should be done.

[image]   (1)

I tried to solve it using Kirchhoff's law, but I did not know if this would work.

Please help me, tell me how I can get formula(1).

Comment: well, yes, it would work, show your calculation (you can just `$$ \text{Math}\cdot\text{equation}$$` and add it to your question, so that we can help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that R1 and R2 are interchanged or V1 and V2?
From a conceptual analysis, you really have a voltage divider. Because R1 is equal to R2, the voltage difference between V1 and V2 is divided by two. 5V / 2 = 2.5V. Therefore, the voltage 'Va' will be 2.5V + 10V.
Mathematically you can see it in the schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f60H1b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You're welcome. It is good practice for the community to accept a response as valid if your question has been resolved:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer
Regards